# How to pass custom screen params to a custom tab bar in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

could someone help me with some stack nested in tabs logic. I have a custom tab bar, I'd want to send extra props to it for every stack, things like icon etc.

My current code

```
const MapStack = createStackNavigator({
  Map: MapScreen
});

const PlacesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Places: PlacesScreen,
});

const ArticlesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Articles: ArticlesScreen,
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Map: MapStack,
    Places: PlacesStack,
    Articles: ArticlesStack,
    Profile: ProfileStack,
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: Tabbar
  }
);
```

And I want to achieve something like

```
const MapStack = createStackNavigator({
  Map: {
    screen: MapScreen,
    props: {
      icon: 'Map'
    }
  }
});
```

In a way that I would be able to see it in my tab bar. To be clear, the properties I want to send only apply to the root of the stack (the whole stack, not to individual screens in the stack)

Any ideas?